# Time out user input csh shell

Tags: input, timeout, csh

Is it possible to time out a user input for the c shell? My code so far is :

```
    #!/bin/csh -f 


    set COUNT = 5
    printf "INFO: Start ok (0/1)? "
    set INPUT = 0

    while ($COUNT > 0 && $INPUT == 0)
      printf "\b%d" "$COUNT"
      set INPUT = <$
      sleep 1
      @ COUNT --
    end

    if ($INPUT == 1) then
    ./execute.sh
    end
```

If no input is given, I want to execute a shell script; if not i want to skip this part.
Unfortunately, the skript does not skip the input part but waits for the input. Any solutions for this problem?
Thanks a lot guys!!!

Answer (score 1):

try this for non-blocking user input in tcsh shell:

```
set TMPFILE = `mktemp`
set COUNT = 5
printf "INFO: Start ok (0/1)? "
stty -F /dev/tty -icanon
while ($COUNT > 0 && -z $TMPFILE)
  printf "\b%d" "$COUNT"
  sleep 1
  (dd bs=1 count=1 iflag=nonblock > $TMPFILE) >& /dev/null
  set INPUT = `cat $TMPFILE`
  @ COUNT--
end
stty -F /dev/tty icanon
echo ""
if ("$INPUT" == "1") then
  ./execute.sh
endif
```